# HTML : Different link at each click

Tags: php, html, url

On a website, I'm trying to create a href link with 6 different urls which will be alternatively showing. For example first person to click gets url 1, second person url 2 etc, then after the 6th person, the seventh will get url 1 again. Is this possible without php ??

Comment: I don't think it's possible without some kind of server side processing, but that doesn't have to be PHP.

Comment: Are these people all supposedly sitting at the same computer/browser session? Because if not, there's no way to serve different content to different people without some server-side support. You could pick one of 6 urls randomly (using javascript) or get the urls on a single page to rotate each click (also javascript) but tracking that user 1 has clicked and the next page should have url2 is where the server-side support comes in. That doesn't have to be PHP.

Comment: @Basic Okay thanks. No those people won't be sitting at the same computer. What I need is to have the same amount of people clicking each link, if I leave this to randomization it probably won't be the case. What do you reckon is the easiest solution?

Comment: Honestly, get some server-side support. It will make you life so much better. You can track who clicked what links, how many times they've been shown, etc, etc... If you're doing this as a personal project, there are a lot of lightweight, easy-to-use webservers with scripting support.  node.js is a webserver that runs javascript and is easy to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not quite clear what you mean by

> Is this possible without php ??

But if you mean "Is this possible on client side?" (so with javascript for example) then, sadly no.

You will have to store the number of clicks somewhere to determine which url should be shown on the website.

Alternetively, if the order of the urls shown doesn't matter you could build a client side randomizer to show one of the 6 urls at random.